# Does the "Association Bonus" affect a question ban?

Tags: discussion, post-ban, association-bonus

I was banned because I deleted my old unanswered questions. The ban was lifted and I have no one last chance to ask a question, which I did not use so far.

However, I am wondering, does the Association Bonus change my rating? Or in other words, do I still have one question left?

Comment: the exact algorithm for question bans is not public. Whether the bonus has an effect or not, try to make your next question as good as it can be.

Comment: Oh cool.I always thought it is rather simple. Do we know if the algorithm considers information from multiple stack overflow branches or does it only look at one branch?

Comment: Branches? There are language-specific Stack Overflows, and there are other sites in the Stack Exchange network, but those are all separate sites with separate rep and separate bans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The post-ban algorithm is secret.

We do know that the post-bans are site-specific, so in general activity in one site has no bearing in a post-ban in a different site.

The sole exception *might* be the association bonus, which could conceivably have an impact since it affect your reputation in the site you are banned.

But no regular user or mod can tell you how it works, since it's not publicly known.

If as a result of the association bonus your ban was lifted, you are very likely still close to the banning threshold. Try to make the most of your next posts, or you could end up being banned again.

Comment: *Very* unlikely: the post ban does not take reputation into account. Worth mentioning also that even question-banned users get 1 free question every 6 months.

Comment: @CodyGray have you *seen* the algorithm or are you simply assuming that it doesn't take reputation into account?

Comment: @Columbia I haven't personally seen the algorithm, but I've gathered quite a bit of knowledge about it via observation and reading Meta posts. Reputation does matter, insofar as an established, high-rep user is significantly less likely to be question-banned than a low-rep user, but I suspect that is more due to correlation (upvotes on questions == reputation gain) than causation.